# serving sites with compiled PHP code

Tags: php, apache, compiler-construction

so apparently it's possible to compile PHP do decouple it from the interpreter:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Php#Compilers

but then once you do so, how would you configure apache so that it'll be able to serve websites using the compiled PHP instead of interpreted PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Running-HipHop

You have an example here on how to compile WordPress and how to run it.

However, for smaller projects it's much better to use APC. It provides extreme speed gain - not as much as hiphop, but you can still use Apache, eval() and run standard php configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the compiler you are using and the OS configuration on which you wish to run the application. A compiler which may be worth looking at is HipHop (developed by Facebook). They have installation and configuration details available here: https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/